# How to pass value from Parent component to child in Blazor

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

so im new in c# and blazor. Currently, im stuck with one issue and im not sure how to solve this. So as i wrote in title, i need to pass a date parameter from Parent component to child. Date is already set dynamically, but im struggling with displaying in when the modal opens up. I will provide you the code down below:

This is the parent component: EnrollmentForm.razor.cs ->

```
private StudentReportingViewModel _studentReportingViewModel;
_studentReportingViewModel = new StudentReportingViewModel()
{
  SchoolYear = SchoolYears[1]
};
```

Date is set properly and i can log and see real date.

In the template - EnrollmentForm.razor i can display the child component(modal) on event click like this:

```
@if (_displayEnrollmentModal)
{
    <ConfirmEnrollmentModal EnrollmentConfirmations="EnrollmentConfirmations" CloseConfirmEnrollmentModal="CloseConfirmEnrollmentModalAsync"/>
}
```

On opening that modal, i should just display that Date in one div like this:

```
    <div class="alert alert-warning mt-3 p-2" role="alert">
--setDateProp--
</div>
```

Any idea how to do this? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is your date stored?  Is it in `EnrollmentConfirmations`?

Comment: I passed the values as props, just like in react. It seems to work just fine for now. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

In your **ConfirmEnrollmentModal.razor.cs** file, add the following property:

```
[Parameter]
public DateTime SchoolYear { get; set; }
```

This means the **ConfirmEnrollModal** component expects a parameter named SchoolYear.

Then in your **EnrollmentForm.razor** pass the date value to the SchoolYear parameter

```
@if (_displayEnrollmentModal)
{
    <ConfirmEnrollmentModal EnrollmentConfirmations="EnrollmentConfirmations" 
     CloseConfirmEnrollmentModal="CloseConfirmEnrollmentModalAsync"
     SchoolYear = "<yourDateValue>" 
    />

}
```

In the **ConfirmEnrollmentModal.razor**, make the following change:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning mt-3 p-2" role="alert">
    @SchoolYear
</div>
```